# Restore original string after converting to integer using intval()

Tags: php

I'm using `intval()` to store a colour value in my database as an integer.

`intval('ff0000', 16); // returns 16711680`

How do I restore the original colour value from the integer value?

Answer (score 4):

You're changing a hex number (three really) to a dec. You can change back with dechex:

```php
echo dechex(16711680); // ff0000
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `dechex($value)` to convert decimal value to hex values.
From your example, `dechex(16711680)` will output `ff0000`